# Bash script to copy *.log files into a new directory

Tags: bash, scripting

In my folder there are different files like this:

```
stats.log
move_2021-05-24.log
sync_2021-05-24.log
application.log
```

I want to copy all *.log files with another day than today to a specific folder.

My current script looks like this but it does not work as I thought. It is currently moving all log files i think and not just log files with a date older that todays date.

```
cd /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/app                 
for file in *.log               
do                                
    day=$(echo ${file} | cut -d"-" -f3)
    now="$(date +'%d')"

    if [ "$day" != "$now" ];       
    then
        mv ${file} ~/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/rclone/logs/    
    fi                            
done
```

I would be glad if I could get advice on how my script would need to look like to work correctly.

Comment: *with another day than today* **or** *with a date older that todays date*?

Comment: Which files from your example do you want to copy?

Comment: `( echo stats.log; echo move_2021-05-24.log ) | cut -d- -f3`

Comment: `find "$SRC" ! -name . -prune -name '*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].log' ! -name "*_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log" -exec echo mv '{}' "$DEST" \;`

Comment: Have you considered logrotate?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you consider `logrotate`. It can do everything you need and more.

But if you want to roll your own, here is how you can find files older than a day and move them. Note: This will overwrite files with the same name at the destination. I added an `echo` statement before `mv` so you can see if looks good to you.

```sh
find /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/app -type f -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1d -print0 | \
while read -rd $'\0' file; do
    echo mv "$file" ~/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/rclone/logs/
done
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response! I am quite new to linux.
How can I setup up logrotate to save the logs to it saves to a specific folder in my case:  ~/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/rclone/logs/ ?

Comment: The scripts that are currently running are creating 2 log files each day in this format: name_YYYY-MM-DD.log I would like to move these files into this folder ~/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/rclone/logs/ each time there is a newer file with the same format.

Comment: Then the application is creating a file "application.log". I would like to "copyturncate" this file and move it to ~/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/rclone/logs/ with this format application_YYYY-MM-DD.log

Comment: Can all of this be done with logrotate? If yes how exactly do I do that I am quite overwhelmed right now by it

Comment: Logrotate consumes configuration files for log files. One of the options is `olddir` which lets you specify where to save rotated logs. First step would be to see if you have logrotate already installed. If so look for sample config files. I don't have access to a linux system right now.